# TFS Workspace Cache

Tags: tfs

I appear to have some problems with my workspace cache.  When I type:

```
tf workfold
```

In my workspace directory, I get the error:

```
Unable to determine the workspace
```

[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/394025c9-e61a-48d1-a35f-9e611d21ca56/) article seems to imply that it’s a problem with the cache.  Being cautious, I tried removing a single workspace:

```
tf workspaces /remove:WORKSPACENAME /server:servername
```

This seemed to work (that is, the command succeeds), because if I do it a second time it fails.  However, when I issue:

```
tf workspaces
```

It still lists this workspace, and I still get the error.

Can anyone give me any guidance of the next step here?  I assume what I’m deleting it the cache for the workspace and not the workspace itself, do I need to clear all my workspaces for this to work?  If so, why might this make any difference?

Comment: I have found this to happen when I had multiple versions of TFS installed, and my path was pointing to a newer version of the tools.  Doing a `tf workspaces /s:server` with the *correct* version of tf.exe fixed this.  Check `%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Team Foundation` and see if you have multiple folders there (1.0 and 2.0, for example).  If so, the `VersionControl.config` files might be out of sync with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Try running below command to refresh the cache:

tf workspaces /s:http://tfs-server:8080

Comment: @pm_2 sometimes you need to clear the workspace cachenon the client first: `tf.exe workspaces /remove:*`

Answer (score 0):

this might be a daft question but are you running the `tf workspaces` command from a folder that's mapped to the workspace? e.g. your workspace mapping is something like `$/MyTeamProject/Source` -> `c:\source`

when you open your command prompt you should `cd c:\source` before running `tf workspaces`

Comment: I don't consider it a daft question, but yes, I am running from the correct directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one to delete the workspace:

```
tf workspace login:[your login credentials] - delete workspacename -collection:[collection URL]
```

example:

`tf workspace login:US\\saket.kumar - delete saketworkspace1 -collection:https://tfs1101.client.com/tfs/CTS`